# convert stored prodcedure to lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have got an assignment that i need to upgrade an old system where eveything is done with stored procedures. So i've been trying to convert this procedure for a while but i just can't get i right.

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetFeaturesForAllLanguages]
  @id nvarchar(50),
 @company nvarchar(50)
  AS
   BEGIN
      SELECT 
        DISTINCT LanguageParameters.Company, LanguageParameters.languageId, LanguageParameters.locale,
             LanguageParameters.ResourcePath, ExtractedFeatures.id, ExtractedFeatures.language,
             ExtractedFeatures.title 
FROM 
    [LanguageParameters] LEFT OUTER JOIN ExtractedFeatures ON [LanguageParameters].company = extractedfeatures.company 
    and ([LanguageParameters].languageid = extractedfeatures.language) AND ExtractedFeatures.id = @id
WHERE 
    [LanguageParameters].company = @company

 END
```

Please help me to convert this to lambda expressions!

EDIT:

Example of a search method i converted from procedure.

```
 using (var ctx = new PamEntities())
            {
                var features =
                    ctx.ExtractedFeatures.Where(w => w.Company == companyName && w.title.Contains(search)).ToList();
                return Task.FromResult(features as IList<ExtractedFeatures>);
            }
```

Comment: Could you post an example of something that you've tried? That'll give us a better understanding of the datatypes you're using. Also, are you using an ORM? If so, which?

Comment: I'll added an example. What is ORM?

Comment: @DanielGustafsson ORM is Object-relational mapper, Entity Framework is an ORM.

Comment: @downvoter what's the reason for down vote?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx may be of interest here since it discusses how to do various types of join (I'm assuming you actually want to convert it to linq rather than a lambda expression).

Comment: I know that lambda is made out of Linq. But i really want to do it with lambda because that's what i'm used to. Like the edit above! To join with Linq looks a lot like SQL but i haven't found any good examples of joining with Lambda

Comment: if you want to rewrite this procedure into a linq query, sorry but you have to join the tables

Comment: Ok, but how do i join using lambda?

Comment: It's funny, I actually converted a bunch of linq queries to stored procedures since you have almost no control on how the sql is generated from linq queries. Stored procedures (or just dynamic sql) can give you better performance.